# MetaStackApps: "Library" Tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, libraries

<sub>*Not sure if this is appropriate here (no Meta site yet), but here goes...*</sub>

I think it'd be a good idea to have a "Library" navigation tab (next to the "Apps tab"), so that people can easily see questions tagged with "library". Thus, we can easily distinguish between apps, libraries, and other stuff.

Comment: HECK YES!!!1!ONE!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be a good idea, as it would immediately clue developers into the resources that are here specifically to make the API easier to use.

Comment: If ChaCha says that it's a good idea, it's actually a good idea. :)

Answer (score 4):

No need, the "apps" tag pulls anything tagged "app" or "library" already.

Alternately, just click [library](/questions/tagged/library) and browse all the libraries.

(sorry, this change has been in for a while, we just hadn't deployed.)

Comment: Why not separate libraries from applications?

Comment: Shouldn't this rather be `status-declined` then, after all @Maxim asked for something distinctly different then you have chosen to implement (and opinions vary on this one indeed)?

Comment: Yeah I'm not interested in any of the existing apps, none of them do anything useful for travel.SE - I want to *make* apps. A "library" tab would be good for developers. I hate digging through all those boring apps to see what's happening with libraries to make my coding easier.

Comment: @hippie so just click the library tag: http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/library done and done.

Comment: Yeah I got a bit melodramatic there (-: It is a tad confusing having both [tag:library] and [tag:libraries] tags though... But I found what I was looking for.